# How to find stored circles by point in Mongo DB using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

I am working about location service which is stored circles within different lat,long and radius.

```
@Document("location")
public class Location {

      private String subject;
      private Circle circle;
    ..
}
```

I want to find all locations that which points are inside of stored circles. Is there any way to query it ?

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends MongoRepository<Location, String> {

  List<Location> findByPoint....(Point point);
}
```